# Update ActiveRecord with a send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I am iterating through a hash, and if the hash key matches the column name (as defined by attr_accessible), then I want to update that column.

```
def self.load_primer3_output(rawfile_hash)
  primer3_output = Primer3Output.new
  rawfile_hash.each do |key, value|
    if primer3_output.class.accessible_attributes.include?(key)
      primer3_output.send(key) = value
    end
  end
  primer3_output.save
end
```

I am getting a syntax error on the send:

```
** [out :: 192.241.193.126]     /home/assay/apps/assay/releases/20130823054701/app/workers/primer3_query.rb:96: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
** [out :: 192.241.193.126] (
** [out :: 192.241.193.126] SyntaxError
** [out :: 192.241.193.126] )
** [out :: 192.241.193.126]
** [out :: 192.241.193.126] primer3_output.send(key) = value
** [out :: 192.241.193.126]
** [out :: 192.241.193.126] ^
```

**EDIT**

**eval** works, by the way. I would prefer to use send though.

```
if primer3_output.class.accessible_attributes.include?(key)
    #primer3_output.send(key) = value
    eval("primer3_output.#{key} = value")
end
```

Comment: what `=` does there? it should be only `primer3_output.send :key, value` refer http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I am trying to assign a value to one of the columns on the table, which has the same name as the hash key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change it to

```
primer3_output.send("#{key}=", value)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I think I understand the syntax better now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

when using `send` method the key should be symbol and string.

change to this when using symbol.

```
primer3_output.send(key.to_sym) = value
```

change to this when using string.

```
primer3_output.send("#{key}=", value)
```

Comment: No, [it can be a string too](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send). acts_as_geek has the correct answer.